# HTML img Tag Not Displaying Image

Tags: html, image

I have an img tag in my code:

```
<img src="P:\MY DOCUMENTS\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApp\Trends\GreenUp.jpeg" />
```

But the image is not displaying.  The syntax of the tag is correct and the path is correct and GreenUp.jpeg exists and I can't think of anything else to check.  I am displaying the web page in Firefox and I found some articles saying FF has problems with .jpeg files -- but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: you have a syntax error in that code sample.  The two sets of quotes in the src attribute.

Comment: Sorry.  That was a typo I made when writing the question.  I have edited the question to show the actual path being used.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? And have you tried the same with a PNG?

Comment: What if you paste `P:\MY DOCUMENTS\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApp\Trends\GreenUp.jpeg` into Firefox? Does it display?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `file:///` prefix:

```
<img src="file:///P:\MY DOCUMENTS\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApp\Trends\GreenUp.jpeg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a Firefox problem after all.

Answer (score 0):

can u try this:
this will work for me...

```
<img src="P:\MY DOCUMENTS\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApp\Trends\GreenUp.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, the IDE must have probably shown a 'light bulb' to the left of your  tag.
Click that and select "Encode in base64"

This issue is specific to Visual Studio, because the same code works perfectly in Notepad regardless of browser used.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, most likely you downloaded the image from the Internet, so windows blocked it as unsafe, you need to unlock it in the properties of the image

Comment: Your answer needs to be improved to include more information about the case mentioned to avoid negative feedback by moderators. When answering, detail more precisely regarding the proposed topic with step by step instructions to carry out such information.